# React Admin dynamic url based on filters in return

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am quite beginners in coding. I have one question, hope you could help me !
I have a little function which returns a  url and I try to make it dynamic, based on filters. I need to make my return dynamic, it means if one oof my filter is unset(so undefined), ex: q=undefined or size=undefined, so in my url I want to delete this part completely :  "q":"${q}". my problem is this part of my url : `..."q":"${q}", "size":"${size}", "color":"${color}"}

```
 rowClick={(id, resource, record) => {
        setSelectedRecord(record.product)
        const { q, size, color } = filterValues
        return `?filter={"details":"${record.details}","type":"product", "q":"${q}",  "size":"${size}", "color":"${color}"}`
      }}
```

I want my url in return was dynamic :/ no idea how to make it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could use some ternary operators and do as:

```
`?filter={${record.details ? `"details":${record.details}",`}"type":"product",${q ? `"q":${q}",`} ${size ? `"size":${size}",`}${color ? `"color":${color}",`}`
```

I am not sure you need all those double quotes, since it's all a string anyway so you should try not using them.

Comment: oh yes ! I didn't even think about it ! i works, thanks a lot ! And do you know how to make it dynamic, like:  "nameofMyFiltter":$"valueofFilter" ? in the case if one day i want to add more filters and don't need to add it every time in my url. It will juste make my code super long

Comment: No worries! Well you could always pass it as like an object like filters = { details: "test", color: "red", type: "product"} and then `?filter=${Object.keys(filters).map(key => `${key}=${filters[key]}`).join(",")` and in case some are undefined, run a .filter before the map

Answer (score 0):

finally, to got all my filters I used a useSearchParams from react which gives me all filters in my url directly.
exemple:
const [URLSearchParams] = useSearchParams()

It works perfectly for me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).